# Logic apps encrypt/decrypt connectors

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I need to pgp encrypt a file before I move it to a specified location in logic apps. I can see a file system connector that i can use to copy files etc. But i am not able to find a connector to PGP encrypt/decrypt. My guess is souch connector does not exist, if so what is the best way to create a custom connector for this?

Answer (score 1):

There's an Azure Function for that.  You'd need to deploy this function configure keys, probably in the Azure Key Vault and then call the function from your logic app.

https://github.com/lfalck/AzureFunctionsPGPEncrypt